# Wordpress auto create posts

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Hello how do I create custom posts inside my index.php file so when someone installs the template it automatically creates like 5 posts?

I tied this:

```
<?php // Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post1',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post8.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post ); ?>
```

But it didn't work. What I am trying to do is create custom posts inside `<div>` tags. So when the users installs the theme they will already be created with the theme and the post will display individually. 
For example:

```
<div class="demo">

                <?php // Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post1',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post8.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="description">
                <span class="big"><?php // Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post2',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post7.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post ); ?> </span>
            </div>
```

Comment: For some reason every time I refresh the page it creates all the posts over and over in the admin control panel in posts.

Comment: This is, near enough, your second duplicate of this question. The assistance [you received here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14606430/472495) answers your question - you are trying to create a post, when you should be trying to display it.

Comment: Addendum: you've asked this same question, in different ways, four times. That creates a lot of duplicate effort. Questions are, obviously, best asked well just once.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the example from [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

1. Make sure you actually have the categories with IDs `8` and `39`.
2. use something like `$var = wp_insert_post($your_args)`. Then echo `$var` to get the ID of the post that was created.