# Wordpress custom post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create custom posts in the code of my template in Wordpress.

```
 <div class="demo">     
<?php global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
'post_title' => 'My New Post',
'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post); ?>
</div>
```

This doesn't seem to display the post on the page?

Comment: I added this in my index.php file. Do I need to add it to functions and then call it from index.php?

Comment: do you get a useful error message when you do `$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post, true); var_dump($post_id);`?

Comment: don't mind, I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: How would I get it to display the post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Create a Post in WordPress Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605868/how-to-create-a-post-in-wordpress-programmatically)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your previous question, which was closed. Replicating a closed question is (a) poor netiquette, and (b) wasteful of people's time. I offered some help in the comments on your last question, but you did not respond.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="demo">     
<?php global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
'post_title' => 'My New Post',
'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post); ?>
```

What above code does is insert a new post. [Read more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

> This doesn't seem to display the post on the page?

What you are trying to do here is inserting a new post. if you want that post to be shown try the below code

```
<?php get_post( $post_id ); ?>
```

[Read more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)

Comment: Where do I need to put <?php global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
'post_title' => 'My New Post',
'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post); ?>    because it keeps creating posts everytime I refresh the page.